# What do you put in RegistrySpec.xml for Izpack installation to set Publisher field

Tags: java, windows, installation, registry, izpack

I'm using Izpack 5 to build an installer for Java application. I have the install.xml correctly configured with Registry listeners and additional dlls so that when the application is installed it is listed under in Windows Control Panel/Program and Features .

However the fields **Publisher** and **Size** are not filled in.

I know I need to create a RegistrySpec.xml file and reference it within the install.xml, but what do I put in it ?

All the examples I've found show examples of replacing the uninstall packages but that is not what I want to do I'm happy with the default uninstaller and dont want to potentailly break that part, I just want to add the publisher and size fields.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the new entries with the respective values within the same keypath as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!-- 
    ATTENTION!!! do not edit with an editor which do not handle UTF-8 in a right manner!!
    Storing with a wrong editor can crash this file!
    Registry definition file for IzPack Installation.
    $Id$
-->

<izpack:registry version="5.0"
                 xmlns:izpack="http://izpack.org/schema/registry"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://izpack.org/schema/registry         http://izpack.org/schema/5.0/izpack-registry-5.0.xsd">

    <pack name="UninstallStuff">
        <!-- Special "pack", if not defined an uninstall key will be generated automatically -->
        <!-- The variable $UNINSTALL_NAME can be only used if CheckedHelloPanel will be used
               because there the variable will be declared. With that variabel it is possible
               to install more as one instances of the product on one machine each with an
               unique uninstall key. -->
...
        <value name="Publisher"
            keypath="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\$APP_NAME $APP_VER"
            root="HKLM"
            string="MyCompany Software Inc." />
...
    </pack>
</izpack:registry>
```

Then you can do the same for the Size field.